# How can I store spatial data in JaguarDB

Tags: database, geometry

What kind of spatial data can I store and how many geometry objects are included in JaguarDB?
Can I store objects like triangle, rectangle or ellipse into the JaguarDB?

Answer (score 1):

You can create geometric objects such as square, circle, sphere, ellipsoid, rectangle, cone and geographic objects such as linestring, polygons, multipoints with srid 4326:
Create table t123 ( key: name char(32), value: s square, g polygon );

Insert into t123 values ('park1', square(3 4 1000), polygon((3 0, 4 2, 4 7, 3 8, 2 6, 1 4, 3 0)) );